# In Flutter, how can I create a string compatible with Firebase documentID?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Flutter,
in Firebase when a Document is added, the documentID is auto generated.
But if the App is Offline how can I create a string compatible with Firebase documentID?

Comment: So actually, Firestore IDs do not have a time component in them.  Realtime Database IDs did, but not Firestore.  Firestore IDs really are just random, and they contain no data, and have no sort order.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution

```
String getNewDocID() {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('').document().documentID;
}
```

DocumentReference document (
[String path]
)
Returns a DocumentReference with the provided path.

If no path is provided, an auto-generated ID is used.

The unique key generated is prefixed with a client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted.

https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/document.html

Answer (score 0):

Now

```
DocumentReference document ([String path])
```

"Is Deprecated in favor of `.doc()`"

So:

```
String getNewDocID() {
            return Firestore.instance.collection('').doc().documentID;
}
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html